# Word document Fields.Update through interop does not trigger custom code

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop, field

I'm trying to open a Word template and update its fields using CustomDocumentProperties in a VB.Net Windows form application. This is working for regular field content, but I want the UpdateFields event to trigger custom code within the Word template.

This is what I have in the Word template:

```
Public Sub UpdateFields()
  'do some things with the CustomDocProperties
End Sub
```

And this is the code from the application:

```
Dim wordApp = New Word.Application
wordApp.Documents.Open(pathToTemplate)
wordApp.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Initials").Value = "JD"
wordApp.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update()
```

The UpdateFields method is triggered when I update the fields in Word itself, but this does not happen when I do this through interop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used following line to call custom method:
`wordApp.Run("InsertSignature", "JD")`